# What is meant by 1D gaussian kernel vs 2D gaussian kernel?

Tags: image-processing, gaussianblur

I am new to image processing and am trying to understand gaussian blur filter. I understand the meaning/idea behind using a gaussian filter and a quick google search gives a variety of different APIs to implement a gaussian filter on an image.
But what I don't understand is -> what is the difference between applying a 1D gaussian filter vs a 2D gaussian filter?
Is a 1D filter only applicable on a 1D array of input? So we need a 2D filter (or 2 1D filters) for a 2D image/signal?
Also, I am having trouble calculating the value of a gaussian filter from a given value of sigma. Assume that I have an input signal and also a value of sigma, how to go about calculating the gaussian kernel for this signal? I did come across some solutions online but I could not understand them. I know the Gaussian function but I cannot seem to understand how we would calculate the entries of the gaussian kernel given the information of input signal and sigma. Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: A 1D Gaussian is a function that depends on only one variable, say x. The 2D one depends on two, say x and y. You can apply a 1D kernel to each image line (image row or image column). The Gaussian is separable, so you can apply the 1D kernel along rows, then along columns, to obtain the same result as the 2D kernel. See [this blog post](https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/22/). Also, the kernel is independent of the signal. The convolution applies the kernel to the signal.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the link to the blog post!